# How do you change .NET SDK version in global.json for child directories?

Tags: .net, sdk

I am trying to use .NET 5.0.405 for a class.

I previously had .NET 7.0.200 installed, but it (should) now be uninstalled.

In my user folder, it is appropriately set. I have tried setting it in child directories with the following:

```
will@blue ~
$ dotnet --version
5.0.405

will@blue ~
$ cd /d/Code

will@blue /d/Code
$ dotnet --version
7.0.200

will@blue /d/Code
$ echo $'{
   "sdk": {
      "version": "5.0.405"
   }
}' > ~/global.json

will@blue /d/Code
$ dotnet --version
7.0.200
```

Neither starting a new terminal window nor restarting the PC has any effect.

This is the only `global.json` on my machine, in `~`

```
{
   "sdk": {
      "version": "5.0.405"
   }
}
```

How can I set the .NET 5 SDK for child directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Visual Studio and my .NET SDKs were installed on the `/c/` drive, but my `Code` folder is on `/d/` drive.

Copying the `global.json` to `/d/` fixed the issue.